# Getting plugin is not implemented with Capacitor 5

Tags: android, next.js, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm getting the following error messages with Capacitor 5, when building for Android.

- Uncaught (in promise) Error: "SafeArea" plugin is not implemented on android
- Uncaught (in promise) Error: "Network" plugin is not implemented on android

This only happens when building a signed APK for production... this does work fine when using `cap sync && cap run android`.

- I already ran `pnpm cap sync android`... and syncing my files with Android Studio does not modify anything

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

- removing the `android` folder
- upgrading all the dependencies (especially the capacitor ones)
- running `cap add android`

rebuild the app